# Maven 3.0.4 not downloading from multiple repositories

Tags: maven

When I am running `mvn clean compile`, it hangs during a download like this because it tries to go to a nonexistent url:

```
Downloading: 
    http://example.com/repository/mypath/junit/junit/4.9/junit-4.9.pom
```

I'm not sure what triggered this, as the projects used to build fine and now it seems like they've stopped working randomly.  I tried deleting my `~/.m2/repository` folder.  I have a total of 4 repositories, and the projects I'm building have dependencies in all of the different repositories.

I think what should happen is it should timeout, then try to download from another (correct) repository.  However, it still hangs even after setting the `<server>` element with a timeout in my `settings.xml` file according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168468/how-to-get-maven-to-timeout-earlier-while-downloading-dependencies):

```
<server>
  <id>MyRepoCentral</id>
  <configuration>
    <timeout>5000</timeout> <!-- 5 seconds -->
  </configuration>
</server>
```

Here's a snippet of the debug output showing the repositories list:

```
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [MyRepoCentral (http://example.com/repository/MyRepoCentral, releases+snapshots),
                                      ThirdParty (http://example.com/repository/ThirdParty,
                                      releases+snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]


[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
```

What should I do or try next?  I cannot just set another repository as the default or higher priority repository, because the project has dependencies from each repository.

Comment: The server element in the settings.xml has no timeout nor a configuration element... see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html Do you use a repository manager ?

Comment: We are using archiva, I'll put my pom.xml file up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Network issue, perhaps due to proxy?  Anywho, it works now.